# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {\ln \left( x \right) \arctan \left( x \right) }{{{\rm e}^{\pi\,x}}-1}}\,{\rm d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I have the idea of this integral when I see $$\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {\arctan \left( x \right) }{{{\rm e}^{\pi\,x}}-1}}\,{\rm d}x$$ and so I know that the closed form is
$${\frac{1}{2}}-{\frac {\ln  \left( 2 \right) }{2}}.$$

But really, I don't know any paper where I can evaluate for example $$\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) \arctan \left( x  \right) }{{{\rm e}^{\pi\,x}}-1}}\,{\rm d}x.$$

In the same time, I see that Wolfram can't give a closed form.

Does someone has an idea please?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that you can find a closed form ?

Comment: The integral is convergent so maybe there a closed form